# How to get Angular routes information like Compodoc? (in compile time)

Tags: angular, compodoc

Can anyone guide me on how to gather information about routes in Angular like Compodoc? (in compile time)

How they get info in the Angular Compodoc?

Does exist any specific functionally for this purpose?

Some information such as:

- Route names
- Relation between routes
- Related components
- and so on

You can find the link [here](https://compodoc.github.io/compodoc-demo-todomvc-angular/routes.html)

[image]